# Relation between level curves and horizontal traces

Tags: tikz-pgf

How can I draw this picture and an animation of this so the concept becomes clear?

[image]

Comment: Which concept do you want to become clear?

Comment: the relation between level curves and horizontal traces

Comment: level curves being lifted up to graphs of functions.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The short answer is that, yes, this is possible *but* I have to warn you that questions of the form "Please draw this for me" that show no effort on the part of OP, often don't get answered. You will get more help if you post some code showing what you have tried and give a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that). A quick search on TeX.SX for drawing functions (with tikz or pstricks) will give you an idea of where to start from.

Answer (score 7):

This illustrates the concept perfectly without animation.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usepgfplotslibrary{colorbrewer}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[axis lines=middle,ymin=0,xmin=0,zmin=0,zmax=50,smooth,
    colormap/PuBu,point meta=-z-x-y,view={115}{30},
    xtick=\empty,ytick=\empty,ztick={0,45},
    declare function={f(\x)=30+15*cos(\x*36);}]
  \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{20,25,30,35,40,45}{%
  \draw[red] (7,7,0) circle[radius={acos((#1-30)/15)/36}];
  \draw[dashed] (7,{7-acos((#1-30)/15)/36},0) --
  (7,{7-acos((#1-30)/15)/36},#1) (7,{7+acos((#1-30)/15)/36},0) --
  (7,{7+acos((#1-30)/15)/36},#1);
  }
  %
  \addplot3[domain=-5:5,color=gray,samples y=0]  ({7},{7+x},{f(x)});
  %
  \addplot3[surf,shader=interp,domain y=0:360,domain=0:5,z buffer=sort,opacity=0.5] 
   ({7+x*cos(y)},{7+x*sin(y)},{f(x)});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or with animation.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16,width=14cm}
\usepgfplotslibrary{colorbrewer}
\begin{document}
\foreach \imin in {40,35,...,15}
{\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={f(\x)=30+20*cos(\x*36);
    finv(\x)=acos((\x-30)/20)/36;}]
\pgfmathsetmacro{\xmax}{finv(\imin+5)}  
\begin{axis}[axis lines=middle,
    xmin=0,xmax=12.5,ymin=0,ymax=12.5,zmin=0,zmax=50,smooth,
    colormap/PuBu,point meta=-z-x-y,point meta max=-20,point meta min=-70,
    view={115}{20},
    xtick=\empty,ytick=\empty,ztick={0,45}]
  \draw[dashed] (7,{7-finv(45)},45) -- (0,0,45);
  \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{45,40,...,20}{%
  \ifnum##1>\imin
  \draw[red] (7,7,0) circle[radius={finv(##1)}];
  \draw[dashed] (7,{7-finv(##1)},0) --
  (7,{7-finv(##1)},##1) (7,{7+finv(##1)},0) --
  (7,{7+finv(##1)},##1);
  \fi
  }
  %
  \addplot3[domain=-5:5,color=gray,samples y=0]  ({7},{7+x},{f(x)});
  %
  \addplot3[surf,shader=interp,domain y=0:360,domain=0:\xmax,z buffer=sort,
    opacity=0.8] 
   ({7+x*cos(y)},{7+x*sin(y)},{f(x)});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: But the z-values should change as the level curve changes. and how to add level curves in the surface as well?