# How to make this level curves diagram exactly like it is

Tags: tikz-pgf

[image]

In this post,

[Relation between level curves and horizontal traces](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/526485/relation-between-level-curves-and-horizontal-traces)

there is a very nice picture already done, but some details are missing. And I can't realize it.

Comment: Could you provide a minimal working example and show what you have already done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some things in such plots are potentially conceptually interesting, and answers may provide other users with information that is to some extent abstract and thus useful. Other parts are just tedious. In order to do the plot in exactly the same way you want, IMHO you should really bring yourself into a stage in which you understand the basics, and then just do it.

The following added a few details to the post you link to, and I'm hoping that this gives you the mileage to achieve precisely what you want.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\makeatletter
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{phicrit}{0}{%
\begingroup%
\pgfmathparse{atan2(\pgf@xx,\pgf@yx)}%
\pgfmathsmuggle\pgfmathresult\endgroup%
}%
\makeatother
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=15cm,
    axis lines=middle,ymin=0,xmin=0,zmin=0,zmax=50,smooth,
    colormap={irk}{color=(cyan!50) color=(cyan)},point meta=-z-x-y,view={115}{20},
    xtick=\empty,ytick=\empty,ztick={0,45},
    declare function={f(\x)=30+15*cos(\x*36);}]
  \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{20,25,30,35,40,45}{%
  \draw[red] (7,7,0) circle[radius={acos((#1-30)/15)/36}];
  \path ({7+cos(-50+5*#1)*acos((#1-30)/15)/36},{7+sin(-50+5*#1)*acos((#1-30)/15)/36},0)
   node[inner sep=0.5pt,fill=white,font=\tiny] {$k=#1$};
  \draw[dashed] (7,{7-acos((#1-30)/15)/36},0) --
  (7,{7-acos((#1-30)/15)/36},#1) (7,{7+acos((#1-30)/15)/36},0) --
  (7,{7+acos((#1-30)/15)/36},#1);
  \addplot3[domain=phicrit+30-#1/3:phicrit+15+180-#1/3,color=cyan,samples y=0,smooth,
    dashed]  
  ({7+cos(x)*acos((#1-30)/15)/36},{7+sin(x)*acos((#1-30)/15)/36},{#1});
  }
  %
  \addplot3[domain=-5:5,color=gray,samples y=0]  ({7},{7+x},{f(x)});
  %
  \addplot3[surf,shader=interp,domain y=0:360,domain=0:5,z buffer=sort,
    opacity=0.8] 
   ({7+x*cos(y)},{7+x*sin(y)},{f(x)});
  \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{20,25,30,35,40,45}{% 
  \addplot3[domain=phicrit+30-#1/3:phicrit-30-180+45-#1/3,color=cyan,samples y=0,smooth]  
  ({7+cos(x)*acos((#1-30)/15)/36},{7+sin(x)*acos((#1-30)/15)/36},{#1});
  } 
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]