# Drawing the Bernoulli lemniscate with level curves

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to draw the Bernoulli lemniscate (see below):

[image]

However, I would like to draw it in a similar way as the picture in the following question, which has already been answered: [Relation between level curves and horizontal traces](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/526485/relation-between-level-curves-and-horizontal-traces)

In particular, I would like to highlight the level curve at the value 0, i.e. where f(x,y)=0 (for f the Bernoulli lemniscate).

Comment: You need to show what you have tried in a Minimal Working Example. You also need to give the math/function of the surface.

Comment: The function is f(x,y)=(x²+y²)²-(x²-y²).

Comment: @rkrapf how to describe the surface? Wolfram Alpha says that it is not `z=(x²+y²)²-(x²-y²)` https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=z%3D%28x%C2%B2%2By%C2%B2%29%C2%B2-%28x%C2%B2-y%C2%B2%29

Answer (score 3):

Well... this is just for fun. The best (vectorial) solution is probably pgfplots. But I was wondering what could be done with tikz, and I've come to this.

I'm plotting the function (1), or in cylindrical coordinates (2). Expression (3) gives rho in terms of theta.
[image]
This is my proposal:

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2,line cap=round,line join=round,
   x={(-0.7766cm,-0.1369cm)},y={(0.6300cm,-0.1688cm)},z={(0cm,0.9761cm)}]
\def\xmin{1}
\def\ymin{0.7}
\pgfmathsetmacro\xstep{\xmin-0.2}
\pgfmathsetmacro\ystep{\ymin-0.1}
\def\h{-1.4} % projection height
% blue lines, sections perpendicular to the x axis
\foreach\i in{-\xmin,-\xstep,...,\xmin}
{%                 domain in which z>=-1
  \pgfmathsetmacro\xdom{min(\ymin,sqrt(-0.5-\i*\i+0.5*sqrt(5+8*\i*\i)))}
  \draw[blue] plot[domain=-\xdom:\xdom,samples=25,smooth]
    (\i,\x,{-(\i*\i+\x*\x)*(\i*\i+\x*\x)+(\i*\i-\x*\x)});
}
% cyan lines, sections perpendicular to the y axis
\foreach\i in{-\ymin,-\ystep,...,\ymin}
{%                 domain in which z>=-1
  \pgfmathsetmacro\xdom{min(\xmin,sqrt(0.5-\i*\i+0.5*sqrt(5-8*\i*\i)))} 
  \draw[cyan] plot[domain=-\xdom:\xdom,samples=25,smooth]
    (\x,\i,{-(\x*\x+\i*\i)*(\x*\x+\i*\i)+(\x*\x-\i*\i)});
}
% Bernouilli's lemniscate (and projection)
\foreach\a in {0,180} \foreach\z in {0,\h}
{%
  \draw[thick,red] plot[domain=-45+\a: 45+\a,samples=25,smooth]
    ({sqrt(cos(2*\x))*cos(\x)},{sqrt(cos(2*\x))*sin(\x)},\z);
}
% Other level curves (and projections)
\def\z{0.2}
\pgfmathsetmacro\xdom{0.5*acos(2*sqrt(\z))-0.005} % precission problem, I think
\foreach\zz in {\z,\h} \foreach\a in {0,180} \foreach\s in {-1,1}
{%
  \draw[red] plot[domain=\a-\xdom:\a+\xdom,samples=25,smooth]
    ({sqrt(0.5*cos(2*\x)+0.5*\s*sqrt(cos(2*\x)*cos(2*\x)-4*\z))*cos(\x)},
     {sqrt(0.5*cos(2*\x)+0.5*\s*sqrt(cos(2*\x)*cos(2*\x)-4*\z))*sin(\x)},\zz);
}
\foreach\z in {-0.2,-0.4,-0.6} \foreach\zz in {\z,\h}
{%
  \draw[red] plot[domain=-180:180,samples=51,smooth]
   ({sqrt(0.5*cos(2*\x)+0.5*sqrt(cos(2*\x)*cos(2*\x)-4*\z))*cos(\x)},
    {sqrt(0.5*cos(2*\x)+0.5*sqrt(cos(2*\x)*cos(2*\x)-4*\z))*sin(\x)},\zz);
}
% axes
\draw[-latex] (0,0,0) -- (2,0,0) node[left]  {$x$};
\draw[-latex] (0,0,0) -- (0,2,0) node[right] {$y$};
\draw[-latex] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,1) node[above] {$z$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]